# How can we pass payment Id from response to request using Regular expression extractor in jmeter?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

[image: Regular expression][image: Request]here I am trying to pass payment id from request to response

[image: Request Body]

Answer (score 0):

Change to simpler regex notice the `"` at the end:

```
 ID=(.+?)"
```

Comment: Still same issue.can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Regular Expression Extractor scope is not correct, you should be extracting the value from the document Body
2. You need to escape this `?` between `htm` and `PaymentID` as question mark is a [meta character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) and it must be escaped unless it is in group or in class

Suggested configuration:

[image]

If you're not too comfortable with regular expressions you could go for [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) instead, in particular this case it would be much easier.